# MySQL query for selecting a or b but not c

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns: branchId, repoId and userId. I need to find users who created branch for repo 1 or repo 2 but not for repo 3. Any help will be much appreciated.

I tried doing the following:

```
select userId 
  from branch 
 where repoId=1 
    or repoId=2 
   and repoId<>3
```

However, this is also outputting userIds which have repoId 3 as other rows with that userId doesn't have repoId 3.

For example, for userid 2, there are 3 rows, with repoId 1, 2 and 3.

The output of the above query is still giving me result as userId 2 beacuse 2 of its rows dont have repoId 3.

Example table:

branchId  repoId  userId
1         1       1
2         2       1
3         1       2
4         2       2
5         3       2

So for this table, the result should be userId 1.

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: I tried doing the following: select userId from branch where repoId=1 or repoId=2 and repoId<>3. However, this is also outputting userIds which have repoId 3 as other rows with that userId doesn't have repoId 3. For example, for userid 2, there are 3 rows, with repoId 1, 2 and 3. The output of the above query is still giving me result as userId 2 beacuse 2 of its rows dont have repoId 3.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: if possible share your structure and data with http://db-fiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below.

```
select userId 
from branch 
where repoId in(1,2) AND userid not in(select userid from branch where repoId =3)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you accept the answer so it will helpful to others